# Notification Values are not updating from older values?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications

i'm trying show a notification in my app...
i declared a sample text as title and body to check whether it is running or not. it was perfect.
then, when i changed the String values(title,body). it is not updated, it still shows old sample text.
i have searched for solutions on the internet. some said adding a flag_update_current would solve.
 i did, but no use.
here is the code.. i used.

```
public void Notify(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    String mbody = "Mode: General";
    String title = "messager On";
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ezmsgr,mbody,System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, mbody, pi);
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    nm1.notify(NID,n);
}
```

i tried assinging new values to unique id of notification too. it is not updating.

Comment: Ooops., my bad. the actual problem is not with notification but with preferences. i added on/off button for notification in preference and it stored all values in preference. i found this after hours of struggle.

Comment: I'm having same issue. And surprisingly the notification some times gets updated and sometimes shows old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need to call `notify()` again each time you want to update the appearance of your notification.
2. You're using a bunch of deprecated APIs to construct your notification. Instead you want to use [Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html), as in:

```
Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ezmsgr)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(mbody)
        .setContentIntent(pi)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
        .setOngoing(true) // ugh, why are you doing this?
        .build();
nm.notify(NID, n);
```

Call `notify()` again each time you want to update the text. You can reuse the same builder or create a new one.

Comment: i made the changes u have mentioned, but it shows only older values. even if i disable notification method by //Notify(); it still shows the older notification.